# VS 2008 Compiler option for flagging uninitialized variables

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

Is there a compiler option in VS 2008 (C++) to expose uninitialized variables?  I'm trying to debug a problem where the "release" build of a DLL does not work but the "debug" build of the DLL does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iirc, setting warning level to 4 will help with this

Comment: If I set to warning level 4 there are tons of messages that appear.  Is there any easy way to find the actual uninitialized variables?

Comment: you can use #pragma to disable the warnings you don't care about

Answer (score 0):

cl.exe sample.cpp /analyze
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3bbz7tz.aspx)'s the link on MSDN

You're looking for warning number [C6001](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5b9aa09.aspx)

Comment: I don't have "Team Edition"...I only have VS Standard Edition

Answer (score 0):

My normal debug builds seem to have this warning enabled:

`warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'xxx' used`

and the warning is not present in a release build.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is still relevant but I was just looking for the same thing and found a solution.

You can manually change the warning-level for single warnings. In your case you have to set the level for this particular warning at least as low as your configured level of default-warnings (usually 1 or 2).

Within the project-settings within the C/C++ settings enter a manual command-line switch:

```
/wYxxxx
```

with Y being the warninglevel (e.g. 1)
and xxxx being the warningnumber in this case you should enter

```
/w14701
```

Cheers